# Emacs lisp tutorial: Weird extra output when adding two numbers

Tags: emacs, numbers

I am following the [emacs lisp tutorial](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/Run-a-Program.html#Run-a-Program) and have just successfully added two numbers:

`(+ 111 234)`

I enter this in a random buffer (Markdown mode, now, if that matters, but the same happens in `*scratch*`), and evaluate it with `C-x C-e`.

However, the bottom line on Emacs does not simply return 345, but it outputs this line:

`345 (#o531 #x159 ?r)`

When I submit `(+ 2 3)`, the output is `5 (#o5 #x5 ?\C-e)`.

What is this extra output? It's not mentioned in the tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same but in octal (`#o...`) and hexadecimal (`#x...`), as well as character syntax.

In Emacs Lisp, non-negative integers and characters are the *same* type:

```
(integerp ?d)
==> t
(characterp 123)
==> t
```

Thus you see `?\C-e` for 5 because <kbd>Ctrl-e</kbd> has the ASCII code 5.

Your `?r` is probably a non-ASCII `r` which has character code 345 in
your locale.

This is documented in [Evaluating Emacs Lisp Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Lisp-Eval.html).

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense! Just out of curiosity: Is that behavior new? Can I somehow turn it off?

Comment: It's been like that as long as I recall, and I find it unobtrusive and occasionally useful, so I doubt that you can turn it off without source code hacking.

Comment: Alright, thanks. It was just confusing because it didn't agree with the tutorial, but that document was started in the late 80s as I just found out. There's even differences to very basic functions like `append-to-buffer` - fun to discover!

Comment: That's probably `?ř`, "LATIN SMALL LETTER R WITH CARON", which has Unicode code point U+0159.